# Stateful Iterators Java

Tags: java, hadoop, iterator

What is a Stateful Iterator?

This question relates to an Iterator defined in Hadoop for performing Joins. As the reference [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/join/ResetableIterator.html) states:

> This defines an interface to a stateful Iterator that can replay
>   elements added to it directly. Note that this does not extend
>   Iterator.

What does 'replay elements added to it directly' mean? How is this iterator different from a usual iterator?

Comment: Not very sure, but perhaps the difference is that each value can only be read once from a normal Iterator as opposed to multiple times here

Answer (score 1):

Here is further information on stateful Iterator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator (look under Generators)

and some further information here:

http://www.itmaybeahack.com/book/python-2.6/html/p02/p02c08_generators.html

and finally here:

http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/trove-1.1b3/src/gnu/trove/TIntIntIterator.java.shtml

> As the iteration is stateful, access to the key/value parts of the
>   current map entry happens in constant time.

Hope this helps.